# Cannot convert from out T in any type than string in c#

Tags: c#, generic-type-parameters

**This is my method for convert**

```
public bool TryGetUserSetting<T>(string userSettingName, out T result)
        {
            try
            {
            var userSetting = Properties.Settings.Default[userSettingName];

            if (userSetting == null)
            {
                result = default!;

                return false;
            }

            result = (T)userSetting;

            return true;
        }
        catch (ConfigurationErrorsException)
        {
            result = default!;

            return false;
        }
    }
```

**But only out result when is value string**

```
if (!_userSettingsProviderService.TryGetUserSetting("SerialPortName", out string serialPortName) || !_userSettingsProviderService.TryGetUserSetting("SerialPortBaudRate", out int serialPortBaudRate)

            var serialName = serialPortName;
            var baudRate = serialPortBaudRate;
```

Return error for baudRate "Use of unassigned local variable 'serialPortBaudRate'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a first call to `TryGetUserSetting` will return `false`, then condition will be immediately assumed as `true` (because of `!TryGetUserSetting(...)`). In this case the second call to the `TryGetUserSetting` will not be executed and `serialPortBaudRate` will remain unassigned. And you trying to use this unassigned variable inside `if` block.
So, you can move declarations for `out` variables before `if` statements

```
string serialPortName = null;
int serialPortBaudRate = -1;
if (!_userSettingsProviderService.TryGetUserSetting("SerialPortName", out serialPortName) || !_userSettingsProviderService.TryGetUserSetting("SerialPortBaudRate", out serialPortBaudRate)
```

You can also replace `conditional logical OR (||)` with the ordinal `logical OR (|)` which will always calculate both arguments even the first one is `true` (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-or-operator-) for details), but this may be unobvious for someone who will read your code.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Thank you sir :) I should use logical OR (I) !